# Cordova android Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android, cordova

My cordova app dies sometimes on android after that the user resume the application.

I can't fix this issue.
I have already made some modifications :

1) `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`

2) I have created a **main.html**

However my application gives sometimes (not always) an application error. Usually after that user resume the application

Comment: I found how to reproduce it systematically.
1. open app MyHomeUp
2. press android "home" button
2.a. The app goes in background
3. wait 11-12 minutes (During this time I used the phone with other app like telegram or whatsapp)
4. reopen the app from the button on the desktop

Expected Result:
App starts and it is possible Connect to gateway and startup

Actual Result:
Appears an arror


Error Code/Message:
Application error
The connection to the server was unsuccesfully. (file://android_asset/www/index.html)

Comment: Got the same, what did you see, user from the past? http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue? I'm experimenting the same on an app I'm developing

Comment: No I haven't. I think that is some timeout of ajax request.